# How to use Express server back end with Nuxt JS

Tags: express, nuxt.js

I just started working with Nuxt JS, and I'm trying to pass a request from the client to my Express server, but Nuxt treats the routes like they were suppose to be pages.

Hence I get the errors page not found in pages folder. Help please.

Comment: Can you please show us how you are "passing a request from client to express server"?

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten into using an express backend with nuxt and it's a great way to go about it. As there is quite a lot steps to take and files to set up it's perhaps beyond the scope of a single answer here to cover what's needed. I'd recommend you start with this [tutorial on codeburst](https://codeburst.io/nuxt-authentication-from-scratch-a7a024c7201b) which covers all the steps you need and can be expanded upon easily once you understand it. Good luck.